# how to bind dropdownlist which is inside the itemtemplate field of datalist control

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, datalist

i have two tables which stores items and itemsizes, a item will have different sizes. i am trying to display the itemsizes for the item in a dropdownlist with in a datalist. my html is as below

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlstCartItems" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="5"
                    Width="580px" ForeColor="Blue" DataKeys="ItemCode"
                    onitemdatabound="dlstCartItems_ItemDataBound">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border: Solid 2px #eeeeee;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="left" style="width: 180px;">
                                    <a href="Videos.aspx?vid=<%# Eval("itemid") %>">
                                        <img src="images/Gallery/<%# Eval("imagename") %>" alt="Image" height="120px" width="185px"
                                            style="border: 0;" />
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 180px;" align="left">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Name:
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="Videos.aspx?vid=<%# Eval("itemid") %>">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblVideoName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>' ForeColor="#06C"></asp:Label>
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Author:
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="Videos.aspx?Authorid=<%# Eval("itemid") %>">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("thm") %>' ForeColor="#06C"></asp:Label></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Technology:
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <a href="Videos.aspx?Techid=<%# Eval("itemid") %>">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("itemcode") %>' ForeColor="#06C"></asp:Label></a>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAvailableSizes" runat="server"  >
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <%--<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="Silver" />--%>
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="#eeeeee" />
                </asp:DataList>

This is my bind method

 var query = (from b in db.CR_CartItems
                         join c in db.CR_CartItems_Sizes on b.ItemCode equals c.ItemCode
                         join k in db.CR_ScrollingMenus on b.ThemeID equals k.MenuID

                         where b.status == true
                         orderby b.updatedat descending
                         select new
                         {
                             itemid = b.Itemid,
                             imagename = b.galleryimg,
                             itemcode = b.ItemCode,
                             thm = k.DisplayName,
                             name = b.posterName

                         }).Distinct();
            foreach (var q in query)
            {

                var query1 = from b in db.CR_CartItems_Sizes
                             join c in db.CR_CartItems on b.ItemCode equals c.ItemCode
                             where b.ItemCode == q.itemcode
                             select new
                             {
                                 b.SizeDesc,
                                 b.ItemCode
                             };

                foreach (DataListItem li in dlstCartItems.Items)
                {
                    DropDownList list = (DropDownList)li.FindControl("ddlAvailableSizes");
                    list.DataSource = query1;
                    list.DataTextField = "SizeDesc";
                    list.DataValueField = "ItemCode";
                    list.DataBind();
                    list.Items.Insert(0, "Available Sizes");
                }


            }
            dlstCartItems.DataSource = query;
            dlstCartItems.DataBind();
        }
```

i have set up a break point at the foreach loop and checked, it is not entering the loop. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the `DataList.ItemDataBound` event:

Assuming you are binding your `DataList` like: (or similar, using a data source control)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.dl.DataSource = GetDataSource();
        this.dl.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Then your `ItemDataBound` handler would look like:

```
protected void dl_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var myDropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("YourDropDownListID") as DropDownList;
        int currentItemID = int.Parse(this.dl.DataKeys[e.Item.ItemIndex].ToString());

        myDropDownList.DataSource = GetDDLDataSource(currentItemID);
        myDropDownList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Finally make sure to register the event in the `DataList` markup

```
    <asp:DataList ID="dl" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="dl_ItemDataBound"
        DataKeyField="Your_Row_ID"
    >
```

Comment: the above code provided by you will add the same fields to all the dropdownlists, my requirement is as the above link. if the image item has two specific sizes in the database it should dispay only two and if it has 4 then 4 only..

Comment: That's not so hard, in fact the code I provided was just show you an example, I just updated it to extract the ID of the current item row and use it to filter the correct data source for each row. **This code should be enough to point you in the right direction**. If you have more questions please let me know.